# Как сделать, чтобы окно перемещалось?

Tags: python, tkinter

Каким образом можно реализовать движение главного окна по экрану, окно создано с помощью `tkinter` и как можно остановить его беспорядочное движение нажатием на ESC?

Comment: перестаньте его беспорядочно двигать, оно и остановится

Comment: Хорошо перестану, только объясните тогда как начать его двигать?

Comment: ```.geometry('+x+y')``` перед точкой укажите ваше окно, вместо x, y - то, насколько хотите его сместить

Comment: @Tester, а не подскажете если вот такая ошибка `bad geometry specifier "+x+y"`, то в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: @ProFirtos а вы x, y заменили на числа?

Comment: Нет, я оставил x и у, я думал их можно использовать как переменные, перед этим написав вот это:
`x = random.randint(0,30)`
` y = random.randint(0,30)`
Хотел добиться того, чтобы окно двигалось в случайно.

Comment: @ProFirtos все верно, так можно, но тогда вам нужно передавать в аргумент ```geometry``` переменные. Напишите так: ```.geometry(f'+{x}+{y}')```, где x и y - названия ваших переменных

Comment: Всё понял, спасибо, осталось только зациклить, но с этим разберусь.